# Using sum() to sum up values with nested foreach()

Tags: xslt, xslt-2.0

I need help in properly specifying the input parameter for sum(). I encountered sum()'s output to concatenate the values instead of summing up.

My goal is: To sum values of **Column6** when **Column2** is "**invoice**"
In the example below, I have **2000** and **1000** for Column6 whose Column is "invoice".
I'm expecting it to display 3000 for `<TotalAmount>`

```
<Root>
<DataArea>
    <Row>... </Row>
    <Row>... </Row>
    <!-- and so on -->
    <Row>
        <Column1>29/03/19</Column1>
        <Column2>cr note</Column2>
        <Column3>092-213280101</Column3>
        <Column4>1,474.98 </Column4>
        <Column5>103.25 </Column5>
        <Column6>2000 </Column6>
    </Row>
    <Row>
        <Column1>29/03/19</Column1>
        <Column2>invoice</Column2>
        <Column3>092-213280101</Column3>
        <Column4>1,474.98 </Column4>
        <Column5>103.25 </Column5>
        <Column6>2000 </Column6>
    </Row>
    <Row>
        <Column1>11/06/19</Column1>
        <Column2>invoice</Column2>
        <Column3>123-123456789</Column3>
        <Column4>100.50 </Column4>
        <Column5>100.50 </Column5>
        <Column6>1000</Column6>
    </Row>
</DataArea>
</Root>

<xsl:for-each
    select="Root/DataArea/Row">
    <xsl:if ... >
        <TransactionSummary>
            <DebitSummary>
                <TotalAmount>
                <xsl:attribute name="currencyID"></xsl:attribute>
                <xsl:for-each select="../Row">
                    <xsl:if test="(Column2 = 'invoice') and (position() > 9) ">    
                        <xsl:value-of select="sum(../Column6)" />
                    </xsl:if>
                </xsl:for-each>
                </TotalAmount>
            </DebitSummary>
        </TransactionSummary>
    </xsl:if>
</xsl:for-each>
```

I tried `sum(Column6)`, didn't work. `Output: 20001000`

I tried `sum(../Column6)`, didn't work. `Output: 00`

I tried `sum(../Row/Column6)`, didn't work. `Output: Cannot convert string "" to a double`

I tried `sum(Root/DataArea/Row/Column6)`, didn't work. `Output: 00`

I'd appreciate any help.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**It seems you want something like this**:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
 <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>

  <xsl:template match="/">
        <TransactionSummary>
            <DebitSummary>
                <TotalAmount currencyID="someId">
                   <xsl:value-of select="sum(/*/*/Row[Column2 = 'invoice']/Column6)"/>
                </TotalAmount>
            </DebitSummary>
         </TransactionSummary>
   </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**When this transformation is applied on the provided XML document**:

```
<Root>
<DataArea>
    <Row>... </Row>
    <Row>... </Row>
    <!-- and so on -->
    <Row>
        <Column1>29/03/19</Column1>
        <Column2>cr note</Column2>
        <Column3>092-213280101</Column3>
        <Column4>1,474.98 </Column4>
        <Column5>103.25 </Column5>
        <Column6>2000 </Column6>
    </Row>
    <Row>
        <Column1>29/03/19</Column1>
        <Column2>invoice</Column2>
        <Column3>092-213280101</Column3>
        <Column4>1,474.98 </Column4>
        <Column5>103.25 </Column5>
        <Column6>2000 </Column6>
    </Row>
    <Row>
        <Column1>11/06/19</Column1>
        <Column2>invoice</Column2>
        <Column3>123-123456789</Column3>
        <Column4>100.50 </Column4>
        <Column5>100.50 </Column5>
        <Column6>1000</Column6>
    </Row>
</DataArea>
</Root>
```

**the wanted result is produced**:

```
<TransactionSummary>
   <DebitSummary>
      <TotalAmount currencyID="someId">3000</TotalAmount>
   </DebitSummary>
</TransactionSummary>
```

Answer (score 1):

You don't need the inner `xsl:for-each` here, you can do it with a single `xsl:value-of` with the conditions in the select

```
<xsl:value-of select="sum(../Row[Column2 = 'invoice' and position() > 9]/Column6)" />
```

Or, in the context of your snippet....

```
<xsl:for-each select="Root/DataArea/Row">
  <TransactionSummary>
    <DebitSummary>
      <TotalAmount currencyID="">
        <xsl:value-of select="sum(../Row[Column2 = 'invoice' and position() > 9]/Column6)" />
      </TotalAmount>
    </DebitSummary>
  </TransactionSummary>
</xsl:for-each>
```